# Intellisense stuck on loading with typescript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Got an issue with intellisense of visual studio code while i'm using typeScript.
When i type 'myobject.', i don't have autocomplete. And when i force it with ctrl + space i got a loading...
If i wait like 5 minutes on the code, i finaly manage to have the autocomplete, but i have to wait like 5 min everytime i want to use the intelisense.

I've tried to use npm install -g typescript.

I've also to check if "TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features" was enable.

Here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@angular/*": ["node_modules/@angular/*"]
    }
  },
  "typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/@types"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "out",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/test.ts",
    "../node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
      "plugins/cordova-plugin-file/types/index.d.ts"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

Can you please help me to make intellisense work properly ?

Answer (score 2):

Try uninstalling "debugger-for-chrome" extension if installed.